# Password reset link sent to gmail not redirecting to Specified page

Tags: angularjs, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi I am working on Forgot password using angularjs and spring mvc.I am able to send password reset link to registered email,using that link they can create new password.But The link sent to gmail not redirecting to reset password page its directly opening home only.Please help.

Here is my forgot password link.
     
              Login

Username
                      
                      Forget your password?Password
                      
                    
                    
                      Keep me logged in
                      sign in
                      
                        You don't have an account yet? Register here

```
              </form>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="register"><a href="#!/register">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
```

After clicking Forget your password? modal will open up i.e

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Enter Email</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">Email :</div>
                <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" ng-model="user.email" class="addUrl form-control"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  ng-click="submitEmail(user.email)">Publish</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.modal-content --> 
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
      </div><!-- end of model adding beats -->
```

Controller.java

```
@Override
    public void passwordReset(String to) throws Exception {
        String subject = "Blogbeats Password Reset Link";
        String body = "<div>Click below link to reset your blogbeats password <a href='http://localhost:8080/blogbeats/#!/forgotpass'>here</a></div>";
        sendMail(to, subject, body);

    }
```

This link will go to registerd mail but when user clicks on its redirecting to http://localhost:8080/blogbeats/#!/home .
how to make it redirect to http://localhost:8080/blogbeats/#!/forgotpass

Answer (score 0):

Is the spring mvc app secured with Spring Security?

Comment: ...Yes its secured with Spring Security

Comment: Perhaps this is the problem? If "forgotPass" is secured it will redirect to the configured login page.

Comment: was this the problem?

Comment: @Simo I think we'll never know the answer :D But i guess it was it